# There was no endpoint listening at {0} that could accept the message. This is often cause by an incorrect address or SOAP action. (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, android, wcf, soap, xamarin

I can normally run the application on the emulator and do some action before, but for some reason this suddenly appeared even though the webservice runs properly on the browser.

[image: error]

I looked for a solution with similar case as this but I can't seem to figure out how to do it because I am using Xamarin which has a different way of adding service reference.

Here are my codes:

ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFSREmployee" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:51678/FSREmployee.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFSREmployee" contract="IFSREmployee"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IFSREmployee" />
        </client>
        <extensions />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQL_HCMConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ADGTAPPS5;Initial Catalog=SQL_HCM;User ID=hcm;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="OFFICEConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ADGTAPPS5;Initial Catalog=OFFICE;User ID=office;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use localhost on your emulator or device to reach your service. You probably need to use your machines IP or a proxy.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I've always been running it using the localhost and it was connecting just fine then this error suddenly occurred after editing something on my webservice and re-added the metadatas on my project.

Comment: I just changed the localhost `http://localhost:51678/FSREmployee.svc` into my IP address but still get same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Already solved by creating a webservice again and now it is working properly.

Comment: I am having this same issue. What do you mean by creating the web service again? The service itself or the service reference? I don't have control over the SOAP service that I need to call, but I can call it without any issue in a console app using WCF, but I get this error using the exact same code from a Xamarin Forms PCL project.

Answer (score 0):

Which emulator are you using it might be the problem of your emulator. Use genymotion emulator it is the works smooth without any problems. And a service hosted on localhost can be accessed through a proxy or with the IP.

Comment: I am using the built in emulator of visual studio.

Comment: Could it be because of the port? Does port expires?

Comment: Already solved by creating a webservice again. How can I avoid this from happening again.